# Can't fetch data from Firebase - unable to find "docs" in data returned despite data existing in backend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCY6DH8F4oc

But can't seem to fetch data from my Firebase backend.

[image]

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import './App.css';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard/Dashboard';
import {db} from './firebase-config'
import {collection, getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore'

function App() {
  const [Students, setStudents] = useState([])
  const studentsCollection = collection(db, 'Students')
  useEffect(()=> {

    const getStudents = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(studentsCollection)

      console.log(data.docs)
      setStudents(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
    }

    getStudents()
    console.log(getStudents())
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Students.map((Students) => {
        return <div><h1>Name: {Students.name}</h1></div>;
        })}
    <Dashboard/>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few things...

1. you're calling your initial get twice:

```
getStudents()
console.log(getStudents())
```

2. When you're processing the array using `map`, your local variable name is `Students` which is also the name of the array!.  Try using `student` instead.
3. Also, the field you're dereferencing when you display the list should be `StudentName`, not `name` according to your data screenshot.

Hope these help :)